# React doesn't render old parts of UI that were created by code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm not exactly sure how to describe the bug, so I will just explain what is happening.

This version is oversimplified and doesn't cause a bug, but it helps to understand my code:

I have an array with three strings strArr. I render them in this way:

```
<p>{strArr[0] + strArr[1]} <span>{strArr[2]}</span></p>
```

Now, if all of the values are static, everything renders fine. However, in my case, I first give the text to strArr[0], then after a second, I assign text to strArr[1], and then, after another second, when I assign text to strArr[2], the text from {strArr[0] + strArr[1]} stops rendering.

What is actually happening is that I'm trying to make a CEO-friendly type-in animation, and here is my actual code for it. (I use the app directory in Next.js 13.2 if this matters).

Now here you can view how the bug looks if I didn't fix it yet and bellow will be my code.
https://portfolio-ea1kinifn-laycookie.vercel.app/

```
"use client";
import Style from "./page.module.css";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

type Props = {};

export default function TypeIn({}: Props) {
  // Animation length in ms
  const aniLength = 2000;
  const text: [string, string, string] = [
    "Hello, my name is",
    " ",
    "Dennis Lonoshchuk",
  ];
  const fullText = text[0] + text[1] + text[2];
  const [displayedText, setDisplayedText] = useState<[string, string, string]>([
    "",
    "",
    "",
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const iterAmount = fullText.length; // subtract 1 because we start at 0 in the array
    let nextIter = aniLength / fullText.length;
    let i = 1;
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (i <= text[0].length) {
        setDisplayedText([fullText.slice(0, i), "", ""]);
      } else if (i <= text[0].length + text[1].length) {
        setDisplayedText([
          displayedText[0],
          fullText.slice(text[0].length, i),
          "",
        ]);
      } else if (i <= text[0].length + text[1].length + text[2].length) {
        setDisplayedText([
          displayedText[0],
          displayedText[1],
          fullText.slice(text[0].length + text[1].length, i),
        ]);
      }
      if (i >= iterAmount) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      } else {
        i++;
      }
    }, nextIter);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1 className="hidden">{fullText}</h1>
      <p
        className={`font-semibold text-4xl sm:text-6xl md:text-7xl
text-stroke-2 pt-[max(76px,32vh)]`}
      >
        {displayedText[0] + displayedText[1]}
        <Link
          href="/contact"
          className="text-transparent dark:text-stroke-white text-stroke-black text-stroke-2
dark:hover:text-white hover:text-black
transition-all ease-in-out duration-300"
        >
          {displayedText[2]}
        </Link>
      </p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Install eslint and fix the warnings (or if you're ignoring the warnings, read them and fix them). `displayedText` is stale in your `useEffect`. Your `useEffect` dependency array needs to be be `[displayedText, fullText, text]`.

Comment: This code has to only exacute once if I add `[displayedText, fullText, text]` to the dependency array the text starts blinking.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to make additional changes to your code. `setInterval` is tricky in React, read over (and use the code from) https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Comment: Well I can see why I need to include `text`, `fullText` but the useEffect is causing change to `displayedText` which can lead to the infinite loop so I don't really think I have to add it there.

Comment: "I don't really think I have to add it there" You sure do! Read my comments please.

Comment: O sorry I didnt notice I had to use `useInterval` and not `setInterval` it makes sense now thank you how ever I don't think it will solve my problem wouldn't it?

Comment: Okay rewriting my code in your way solved the problem do you want to make a post so I could mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer the question you're asking about, your `useEffect` hook is missing dependencies, it should be `[displayedText, fullText, text]`.

React components "render" multiple times, meaning in your case `TypeIn` gets run multiple times. Each time, functions and variables get re-created in the component/function body. `displayedText` keeps getting updated, but the `useEffect` callback function is never recreated, because you told React not to recreate it since it has no dependencies, by marking the dependency array as `[]`.

You may already know about closures, but if you don't, you should research them. Your `useEffect` callback function closes over the initial variables in the component body (like `displayedText`). When you call `setState()`, the component re-renders with the new `displayedText` set, but the `useEffect` callback isn't re-created, so it's still using the stale `displayedText`. Another common way to describe a closure is a function (the useEffect callback) holds on to a "snapshot" of variables in the outer scope (the component function).

The core issue you have is calling `setInterval()` inside `useEffect()`, which is a tricky thing to accomplish properly in React. You should use the code from (and ideally read all of) ["Making setInterval Declarative with React Hooks"](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/) instead of calling `setInterval` the way you are.

If you haven't already, you should also install eslint in your project with the [react plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react) and make sure it shows errors and warnings inline in your editor as you type. You generally shouldn't ignore React dependency warnings unless you have a very specific use case / control flow that you know won't cause a bug.